# What is the new shuriken formed from Naruto and Sasuke's power?

Tags: naruto

In the end of chapter 634, the latest chapter of Naruto Shippuden, Naruto's shuriken and Sasuke's arrow mixed together and formed a new black kind of shuriken to attack the ten tails.

What kind of power does the new shuriken contain? It contains Naruto's Wind element, but which of Sasuke's powers does it contain?

[image: New Shuriken]

Is it the "Amaterasu" OR "Lightning" element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a **[blaze element](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Blaze_Release)** technique (an enhanced Amaterasu with help from Naruto). What is is called? Well according to the said chapter:

[image]

They could call it "[SHAKUTON KOURIN SHIPPUU NO YA ZEROSHIKI (read: Swirling Gale of Black and White Arrow)](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Scorch_Release:_Halo_Gale_Jet_Black_Arrow_Style_Zero)!"

Comment: Hmm, not sure if it's a good idea for us to be using a scan watermarked with an illegal distribution site.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not really aware of that.

Comment: It's good that you included the page as proof for your answer, but it has a watermark showing that it's from a site which illegally distributes the manga. Just as we don't allow questions about where to get illegal fansubs, I don't think it's a good idea to include this watermarked image since it is promoting an illegal site.

Comment: @atlantiza the official policy is that we are not lawyers and we don't care unless some copy holder starts complaining, and even that it's the problem of the [se] staff, and not ours. Carry on.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha This is not about copyright of the image but rather promoting illegal distribution methods such as fansubs and manga browsers

Comment: @atlantiza: Again, we are not lawyers and don't need to think of such things. If an image is supplementary to a good answer or question, I don't care where it came from.

Answer (score 7):

It contains Amaterasu. In Naruto, wind is superior to lightning and in fact defeats it. What Naruto stated earlier in the chapter was that he was glad that his wind could fuel Sasuke's fire with his powers - and the image is clearly black and colored like Amaterasu. He manipulates Amaterasu through his Blaze Release: Kagatsuchi.